# Cannot IP Forward From a Physical Linux Server to a Docker Container Running on Another Physical Server and Vice Versa

Tags: linux, networking, ip, routing, docker

## TLDR;

I have three servers, Server A, B, and C. Server A and B are physical servers on the same subnet. Server C is a virtual server, a basic WireGuard Docker Compose container running on server B, connected to it via a bridge network driver.

```
                         10.0.1.0/24
                            --^--
                  10.10.10.0/16
                --------^--------
       10.0.0.0/24
    --------^--------

    [ A ] ..... [ B ] ..... [ C ]

      ¦           ¦           ¦
      ¦           ¦
      ¦           ¦      wg0:  10.0.1.1  ❮┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┒ 
      ¦           ¦     eth0: 10.10.10.2          ┇
      ¦           ¦                               ┇
      ¦           ¦                               ┇
      ¦                                           ┇ ping
      ¦    eth1:  10.0.0.1                        ┇
      ¦  br-XXX: 10.10.10.1                       ┇
      ¦                                           ┇
      ¦                                           ┇
                                                  ┇
eth1: 10.0.0.2  ❮┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┅┚
```

##### GOAL

I am trying to establish a connection between servers A at `10.0.0.0/24` and C at `10.0.1.0/24` by using the server B as a router and set up routing table and IP forwarding ***without NAT***. So essentially I have to be able to do a successful ping both ways:

```
serverA:~$  ping -I 10.0.0.2 10.0.1.1
serverC:~$  ping -I 10.0.1.1 10.0.0.2
```

##### EXPLANATION

I'm able to ping from B to both devices. C can also ping B, but not A. A is also not able to ping C. I've kept `tcpdump` open but it didn't capture any ICMP packets.

Firewall allows all outgoing traffic plus all incoming icmp/tcp/udp on all ports from `10.0.0.0/24` and `10.0.1.0/24` on all devices. My routing for A has `10.0.1.0/24 via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1` and IPv4 forwarding is set to `1` on all servers.

What am I missing? How can I establish a connection and ensure correct routing between A and C? Essentially I want to be able to successfully run `ping -I 10.0.1.1 10.0.0.2` from C or `ping 10.0.1.1` from A.

---

I've provided more specific details below in order to eliminate the need for unnecessary back and forth.

##### [DETAILED INFORMATION](https://gist.github.com/sepsol/d06190f91a3a4cb5d22d25b9605bb0ea)

> Apologies for the long post in advance, it was hard for me to compose, let alone reading and analyzing it. I wish StackOverflow supported accordions just like GitHub's `<details>`-`<summary>` tags to organize the content better.

Comment: For iptables, please always use _at least_ `-L -v` instead of just `-L`, as otherwise it omits important fields like the in/out interfaces. (Personally I find the `-S` output far more readable...)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've updated the post details with the recommended changes

Answer (score 0):

I think when source and destination are at different networks, you need MASQUERADE.

On the B: `iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.248 -d 10.0.1.1 -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: But I specifically want to be able to communicate with server A (`10.0.0.248`) from C (docker container) using the `wg0` interface or even the IP space for the VPN peers which is at `10.0.1.0/24`. Can't B just act as a router and forward packets without being concerned about the subnets?

Comment: Different networks is not what makes masquerade necessary – it's only needed when the target network lacks a route back to the source (and when adding that route is not feasible for some reason, like when the Internet lacks a route back to your 192.168 LAN).

Comment: I see, considering the `DETAILED INFORMATION` I shared above and the fact that I have already added the routes to my routing tables, and the fact that NOT masquerading the src/dst IPs is one of the requirements, where do you think I've gone wrong?